# How to put a list under an \item in tablenotes?

Tags: errors, lists, threeparttable

I've tried to put a list under an `\item` in `tablenotes` of a `threeparttable`, but both `itemize` and `enumitem` gives me the error:

> LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

Here is my mwe, see the commented lines:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Example of table}\label{tab:mytab1}
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
            \toprule 
            \addlinespace
            First column header\tnote{a}\ & Second column header\tnote{b} & Third column header\\
            \addlinespace
            \midrule
            1 & 2 & 3\\
            A & B & C\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]                       
            \footnotesize
            \item[a] I'd like to have a list here:
            %\begin{enumerate}
            %   \item first item
            %   \item second item
            %\end{enumerate}
            \\
            \item[b] Another table note.
        \end{tablenotes}     
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @campa Without the option `para` it works, thank you! If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I took the liberty of making your MWE a little more minimal. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard definition of `tablenotes` is basically

```
\def\tablenotes{\TPTdoTablenotes}
\let\endtablenotes\endlist
```

and `\TPTdoTablenotes` issues `\list`, and you can nest a further list there. The package option `para` does basically

```
\let\TPTdoTablenotes\TPT@doparanotes
\def\endtablenotes{\par}
```

and `\TPT@doparanotes` redefines `\item` to print the notes one after another; inserting a list there fails.

According to the documentation you can give the option `para` to the package and restore the normal behaviour with the option `normal` for a single `tablenotes` environment. However, I haven't found anything in the code that actually does this, so either I misunderstood something or when the option `para` is given globally there is no way to reverse it. My suggestion is therefore to call the package without options (well, `flushleft` is OK), and use the option `para` for a single `tablenotes` environment if you really want it.

Comment: The option `[para, flushleft]` given both globally and locally was a mere typo (I put it locally at first, then I changed my mind and put it globally but I forgot to delete the local option). Thank you for having posted a detailed answer.